# converting date time failure with datatype varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database table name = "SearchTask" looks like this 
Data types of columns

```
Task = varchar
AssignedDate = varchar

  **Task | AssignedDate**
    A    | 01/02/2016
    A    | 02/03/2016
    A    | 05/04/2016
    A    | '
    A    | '
```

PS: 3rd and 4th row are char(39), they are added when the user does not want any assigned date and this rule cannot be changed. It has to be like this by the customer.

Now when I write a query

```
select task, AssignedDate
from SearchTask
where AssignedDate not like char(39)
      and convert(varchar(10), convert(date,assigneddate, 105),112) >= 20160301
      and convert(varchar(10), convert(date,assigneddate, 105),112) <= 20160331
```

it gives me error message

conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Can someone please help on this?

But my real question would be 
How can I write a query that should print output when

1. When one of the AssignedDate from between is null it should print
   all the values excluding char(39)

   2. When both AssignedDate from both the between clause is null it should print all value including char(39)

Up on request I am adding more sample data and expected output:

```
 **Task | AssignedDate**
   A    | 01/02/2016
   A    | 02/03/2016
   A    | 05/04/2016
   A    | '
   A    | '
```

If my condition says:

**scenario#1**

```
where AssignedDate not like char(39)
    and convert(varchar(10), convert(date,assigneddate, 105),112) >= 20160301
    and convert(varchar(10), convert(date,assigneddate, 105),112) <= 20160331
It should print me:
A    | 02/03/2016
```

**scenario#2**

```
where AssignedDate not like char(39)
    and convert(varchar(10), convert(date,assigneddate, 105),112) >= 20160201
    and convert(varchar(10), convert(date,assigneddate, 105),112) <= null
```

it should print me:

```
       A    | 01/02/2016
       A    | 02/03/2016
       A    | 05/04/2016
```

**scenario#3**

```
where AssignedDate not like char(39)
    and convert(varchar(10), convert(date,assigneddate, 105),112) >= null
    and convert(varchar(10), convert(date,assigneddate, 105),112) <= 20160301
```

it should print me:

```
 A    | 01/02/2016
 A    | 02/03/2016
```

Comment: Can you add more sample data and expected result. Make sure the sample data cover the given scenarios in question

Comment: r u trying to convert dd/MM/yyyy to yyyyMMdd?

Comment: Scenarios 2 and 3 make no sense. Never compare with `null` with such operators, because they ***always*** yield false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for replying late: 
I was able to solve the above query by using above helps provided by you all. First thing I did was took the user input for the date using the date picker and used the following variable @AssignedDateFrom and @AssignedDateTo and then finally I used the following query:

```
where 
  (@AssignedDateFrom is null or 
        (len(assigneddate)<>1 and
         convert(date,substring(assigneddate,1,10),103)>=@AssignedDateFrom
        )
  )
 and 
  (@AssignedDateTo is null or 
       (len(assigneddate)<>1 and
        convert(date,substring(assigneddate,1,10),103)<=@AssignedDateTo
       )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The most important lesson to be learned: **Never** let your customer design your database.
You should have used a nullable `date` or `datetime` column to keep dates instead of the `varchar` you are using now, and let the presentation layer show the `char(39)` whenever this column contains `null`.

If you can't change the database, you should change your sql:

```
SELECT task, assigneddate
FROM SearchTask
WHERE CASE WHEN assigneddate <> '''' THEN convert(date,assigneddate, 105) ELSE '1900-01-01' END >= '2016-03-01'
AND CASE WHEN assigneddate <> '''' THEN convert(date,assigneddate, 105) ELSE '9999-12-31' END  <= '2016-03-31'
```

Using the `case` statement prevents the database to try and convert `char(39)` to `datetime` values. This is not the case when in your original query, since Sql server does not guarantee short-circuit conditions.

Please note that if you can change the database structure then it is the best course of action.
Read more about it here: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) by Aaron Bertrand.